# Android: Publishing an App in Google Play

Tags: android, publishing

I have developped an applicaction that basically download a file from a Server via Bluetooth and store it in the memory of the mobile phone.

I read what is needed to publish and application in http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/publishing_overview.html
 and I followed the steps:

1. Remove any "android:debuggable" in the Android Manifest.
2. Remove any Log calls
3. Sign the file: Right click on the project->Export -> Android ->
   Export Android Application ... during the process I use an
   AppKey.keystored that I created before.
4. I apply Zipalign
   http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#signing-manually

Once I finish that I upload the App to the Google Play Store.

I downloaded it with three diferent devices, with the following version of Android:

- 4.2.2 (It is the one I used to develop, debbug and test the App while writting it on Eclipse)
- 4.3
- 4.4

But it only works properly in the device with 4.2.2. In the other two devices the Application crash when I launch it.

This is the Android manifest of the Application, all the code is too long to upload it here. But I feel there problem must be or in the manifest or in the way I'm exporting/signing the file.apk

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.cliente_bluetooth"
    android:versionCode="3"
    android:versionName="1.3" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />


    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

       <activity
            android:name="com.cliente_bluetooth.Cliente_Bluetooth"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>


    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is the link of the App in the Play Store:
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cliente_bluetooth

Can anyone find a mistake in the process of publishing? am I skipping or missunderstanding any step?

Thank you very much for your time

Comment: If app publish successfully and then crashing on device then it would be problem of you code. Please go to playstore publish account and check the exception it will show you the log details with exception. Please post that or may be you can solve that by yourself (You can check log through eclipse if you have that device)

Comment: Thank you very much Sadiq, I found the problem. I was checking the content of a folder before creating it (in case it doesn't existe yet). It only worked in the first device because I created that folder long time ago, but it doesn't exist in the other phones.

Thank you very much for your recommendation, that log is a very useful tool. Since this is my first publication I didn't know it, but I feel in the future it will solve me lots of problems. So thanks again!!

Comment: Glad it worked for you.